# Using CSS transforms for proportional sizing and spcing

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I want to use CSS transforms to do some layouts of images, and have the image layouts be consistent across different screen widths.  (For the purposes of this post, I’m only going to discuss widths and x (left) values.)   All the data that I need to do these layouts are in a database.

Of course, if I could do an HTML layout with dedicated styles for each layout, I’d be fine.  [I could do it like I have it here in this pen.](http://codepen.io/geohacker/pen/LWrpye)  There are three boxes, 2 smaller ones and a larger one that is 3 times the size of the smaller ones. The smaller boxes are each 10% of the window width, the larger one is 30%.  The boxes are equally spaced, the left-most one is 10% from the left, the larger middle one is 30% from the left and the last one is 70% from the left.  This leaves an equal amount of space ( 10% ) between the boxes.

```
img#smallA {  /* CSS for the first box */

position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: 10%;
width: 10%;
}
```

[image: Spacing is uniform]
**The spacing is uniform when using CSS only.**

On the above pen that uses CSS only, you can resize the window width all you want and the sizing and spacing stays consistent; proportional to the screen width, just as we have coded it to do.

So it seems logical that one should be able to do the same thing with a transform.  You can get the window width with JS, you can set the width of the boxes with the transform and you can set the x values with the transform.  [But here’s the pen where I’ve tried to do it.](http://codepen.io/geohacker/pen/ryKxmv)  Click the larger box to run the sizeAndPos() function.  Now if you resize the window width to 1000 pixels (watch the little gizmo in the center of the CodePen screen), this JS / transform method works perfectly and the layout looks like the other one.  But if you stretch it, the spacing starts going off immediately. (Remember to click the larger box after resizing).  I think the reason it works at 1000 pixels wide, is b/c at that window width, the boxes are at their natural width.  But I don’t understand why it only works in that case.

[image: spacing is off when using transforms]
**The spacing is off now; the between gap box 2 and 3 is too big.**

For anybody how looks at the code, you may wonder why I’m passing the original width of each image (origWidth) to the function.  This is because the CSS scale transform function sizes the image based on it’s original dimensions (scaling an image to 1 gives you 100% of the original size).  So to do a proportional size, you first have to figure out how many pixels wide the box should be (10% or 30% of the screen width, depending on the box).  Then you have to divide that amount by the original size to get the proper ratio to do the scaling.   The small boxes are 100 pixels wide and the large one is 300 pixels wide.

Surely this is possible with transforms.  I have tried setting the transform properties individually, to control the order of the operations, but it didn’t help.  Can anyone tell me why this doesn’t work?

Answer (score 0):

After trying to make this way too complicated, I found the answer.  Change the transform-origin property of the elements.  The default on this property is 'center' both axis.  But we need our transformations to originate from the top left corner.

```
img#smallA {

    transform-origin: left top;
    position: absolute;

}
```